# Sample YAML Configuration Files for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The [MongoDB configuration options documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) lists all the available options that can be specified, but does anyone have a set of fully formed example YAML formatted config files for MongoDB instances in various roles?

A set of examples for the common roles would be a very useful starting point for those starting from scratch, or looking to test with the latest configuration file format.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here are several examples of [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) configs for Linux (Windows paths and options are a little different), essentially explicitly setting some defaults and commonly used settings.

First, a standalone `mongod` with the default port, path, journal settings - this would be the type of configuration used for local testing, with a few extras so show the general style:

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/db"
    directoryPerDB: true
    journal:
        enabled: true
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/data/db/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
    port: 27017
    wireObjectCheck : false
    unixDomainSocket: 
        enabled : true
```

Some notes on this config:

- You generally don't want to have the object check off (`wireObjectCheck: false`) in production, but for a bulk load of data for testing purposes, it will speed things up a little and is a minimal risk in such an environment
- This would not work for replication unless all member of the replica set were on the loopback IP address (as this is the only binding specified), so beware

Now, let's look at a sample config file for a typical production replica set member with authentication enabled and running as part of a sharded cluster:

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/db"
    directoryPerDB: true
    journal:
        enabled: true
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
replication:
    oplogSizeMB: 10240
    replSetName: "rs1"
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 192.0.2.1
    port: 27018
security:
    keyFile: "/data/key/rs1.key"
    authorization: "enabled"
sharding:
    clusterRole: "shardsvr"
```

Some notes on this configuration:

- Again there are explicit declarations of defaults and implied settings (port is implied by clusterRole for example), generally this is recommended to avoid confusion
- The IP binding is now the external IP address only, so communication on the loopback IP will now fail, but replication can work to remote hosts
- The oplog defaults to 5% of free space, so it is common on large volumes to be more conservative and explicitly set the size allocated

Next up, a sample `mongos` config:

```
sharding:
    configDB: "config1.example.net:27019,config2.example.net:27019,config3.example.net:27019"
    autoSplit: true
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongos.log"
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 192.0.2.2
    maxIncomingConnections: 5000
security:
    keyFile: "/data/key/mongos.key"
    authorization: "enabled"
```

The only required changes here are removals that don't apply to the `mongos` (since it does not store data) and the addition of the `configDB` string, which must be identical on all `mongos` processes.  I added the maximum connections setting as an example, it's not required but can often be a good idea for larger clusters.

Rounding out the sharded cluster we have a sample config server, which is really a subset of the replica set member with some minor changes:

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/db"
    journal:
        enabled: true
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: 192.0.2.3
    port: 27019
security:
    keyFile: "/data/key/config.key"
    authorization: "enabled"
sharding:
    clusterRole: "configsvr"
```

Finally, MongoDB 3.0 (not yet released at the time of writing this) will introduce several new options, especially with the introduction of the new storage engines.  Therefore, here is an example of how to configure the same replica set member, but this time with the WiredTiger storage engine and (the default) snappy compression method (note: altered from original because of [SERVER-16266](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16266), and added sample `engineConfig`):

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/db"
    engine: "wiredTiger"
    wiredTiger:
        engineConfig: 
            cacheSizeGB: 8
        collectionConfig: 
            blockCompressor: snappy        
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
replication:
    oplogSizeMB: 10240
    replSetName: "rs1"
processManagement:
    fork: true
net:
    bindIp: "192.0.2.1,127.0.0.1"
    port: 27018
security:
    keyFile: "/data/key/rs1.key"
    authorization: "enabled"
sharding:
    clusterRole: "shardsvr"
```

As a final bonus addition, I showed how to bind multiple IP addresses using a list, in this case an external IP and the loopback IP.

Comment: Thanks again Adam for this as it is very useful information. I particularly like that there is some insight given to 2.8 storage engine configuration. The one thing I just want to add is that the "processManagement" config is something most people want to omit when running under another "process manager" Ubuntu upstart being a common one. So you don't want to "fork" there and leave it up to the manager to handle that part of configuration. Best example of YAML config out there though so my +1

Comment: Very useful. Interesting, will it be 2.4 configuration file format remains for backward compatibility with 2.8 and further?

Comment: Not sure exactly when it will be removed, but as far as I know, it will be retained in 2.8.  Any removal will be communicated well in advance, of course

Comment: Just in case anyone wants a setParameter example, see this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87653/6441