# How to add setParameter in mongod config?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

When I am using setParameter in mongod config, I start mongod with error:

```
Unrecognized option: setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=1
```

How can I use setParameter from config file ?

P/S: I am using YAML config file format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a working example that I just tested using 2.6.6 - I specified two parameters just to show how it is done for reference:

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/data/db/test"
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/data/db/test/mongodb.log"
processManagement:
    fork: true
setParameter:
    enableLocalhostAuthBypass: 1
    enableTestCommands: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

to set without mongod restart you can use like this example:

```
db.adminCommand( {
   setParameter: 1,
   logComponentVerbosity: {
      verbosity: 1,
      query: { verbosity: 2 },
      storage: {
         verbosity: 2,
         journal: {
            verbosity: 1
         }
      }
   }
} )
```

Comment: Does this update the configuration for the next restart, or does this simply change the parameter for the currently running mongod process?